# Can a numerically unstable algorithm be useful?

Tags: numerical-methods, soft-question

Can a numerically unstable algorithm be useful?

What a numerically unstable algorithm can be useful for? (except of finding solutions on short intervals)

Suppose I have an unstable numerical algorithm (and no other known algorithms) for solution of an important problem. What utility can I have from knowledge about such an algorithm?

Sorry for an imprecise question, I am only in beginning of understanding this, but it is *very* important for me. So I dare to ask here an imprecise soft-question.

I do not try to define numerical stability precisely in this question, because the question is anyway philosophical.

Comment: An unstable algorithm on good data is not necessarily a problem.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think this time the data is bad

Comment: Which "this time" ???

Comment: @YvesDaoust It would be a strong offtopic to answer your question.

Comment: Could you please give at least part of the definition of what you mean by "unstable"? I know "unstable algorithm" as a sort of sorting algorithm, but that has not that much to do with numerics, so I guess you might mean that the algorithm introduces some error?

Comment: @Dirk No, numerically unstable algorithms are not related to sorting. Numerically unstable algorithm is one which may produce not a smally wrong result when the input data is only smally wrong. (This can be easily formalized with epsilon-delta.)

Comment: @porton: you never spoke of a precise case, hence my question which "this time" ?

Comment: If you have some control over the unstability (i.e. "the error might increase, but only by a factor of 2"), then this might still be good to get close to the result, and then start other algorithms from that point.

Comment: @YvesDaoust OK, under the risk of being downvoted (but why? my question is a valid question for a math forum), I will explain my problem: I noticed that fragments of Bible (particularly when understood in nonstandard/spiritual way) form some wonderful "patterns" related to different things of for example the modern world. But when I tried to apply these patterns in practice, I noticed that they tend to break. I concluded that trying to follow Bible is numerically unstable. I want to know what else can I do with the Bible.

Comment: What you're talking about is not numerical instability, since there are (presumably) no numerical computations going on when you notice patterns in the Bible. Rather, on the technical side, see [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting); on the psychological side, [apophenia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apophenia).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know something about the classes of problems for which the instability manifests itself or you have some measure of the magnitude of the instability, then you can use that information to decide. For example, Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting is the default algorithm for solving linear systems even though it is known to be numerically unstable on certain problems. This is not really an issue, however, because these types of problems rarely show up in applications for whatever reason.